# WPF custom border/panel

Tags: wpf, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm quite new to WPF development and I am unable to find a decisive answer about how to implement a custom border/panel (or drop down menu) that looks something like this:

[image: Image of Wpf custom drop down menu/panel]

The idea is to make a drop down menu/panel(**with the centered arrow**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should point you in the right direction:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Polygon
         Fill="LightGray"
        Grid.Column="1">
        <Polygon.Points>
            <Point X="12" Y="0" />
            <Point X="0" Y="24" />
            <Point X="24" Y="24" />
        </Polygon.Points>
    </Polygon>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
</Grid>
```

Of course, you can customize it as you see fit... 
Notice that in this example I set the height and width of the top-middle cell to make the arrow 24X24

Comment: Thanks for this, now I only need to figure out the popup combination.